# Maximum recursion depth in python

Tags: python, tail-recursion

How can I rewrite this code to compute a number, a raised to a power, b without exceeding the maximum recursion depth

```
def power(a,b):
  if isinstance(a,(int,float)) and isinstance(a,(int,float)):
    return power(a,b)
  else:
    raise TypeError("Argument must be integer or float")
  if b == 0:
    return 1
  elif b == 1:
    return a
  while b >=1:
    return a * power(a,b-1)
  if b == 0:
    return power(a,b)
```

Comment: `return a ** b`?

Comment: Your function makes no sense whatsoever. It goes into infinite recursion at once.

Comment: The while-loop is unnecessary. Recursion *is your loop*. As written, you infinitely recurse in your `if` block. You don't want a recursive call there, that doesn't make any sense. Just forget about the type-checking, you probably don't even want it in the end. Just get it to work first.

Comment: This looks like a university lab question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several flaws and logical errors.

As DYZ already mentioned in the comments, your function immediately goes into an infinite recursion, if a and b are numbers: you try to return the exact same call to power().

```
def power(a,b):
  if isinstance(a,(int,float)) and isinstance(a,(int,float)):
    return power(a,b)
```

Since you already put some conditions into your function, which will return something different, you seem to understand there have to be some kind of stopping conditions.

Your correct recursive call is:

```
return a * power(a,b-1)
```

This returns a different call of your function, thus won't lead to an immediate infinite recursion.

Your stopping condition is also correct:

```
if b == 0:
    return 1
```

Checking for `b == 1` is unneccessary, since it will get caught by `b == 0` in the next recursion, as pointed out in Prunes answer.

Putting all that together in the correct order, you get

```
def power(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a * power(a,b-1)
```

The checking for instances of int or float should in my opinion be done outside of the function. You also have to take into account, that this only works for positive `b`s.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check argument validity in a wrapper function; you're wasting a lot of time and modularity checking on every iteration.  Also, you need to check **b** as well; in this code, you checked **a** twice.  Finally, your logic assumes that **b** is an integer, so you need to restrict your validation.

Remove your b==1 base case: b==0 will catch it on the next iteration.

Remove the while loop: that's the iterative solution.  Your recursive solution is simply a check for base condition (b==0); otherwise, return a*power(a, b-1), as you're already doing.